# python search and replace using variables

Tags: python, regex

User providing me with search expression, e.g. "^.*/bin/run.sh"
Need to scan a file and replace search expression and replace with value also provided by user.

`search = "^.*/bin/run.sh"

replace = "/path/to/bin/new_run.sh"`


how do I search and replace in python 3?

Comment: `str.replace()`?

Comment: You *are* using regex, right ?

Comment: Yes using regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) module's `re.sub` method.

```
oline = re.sub(search, replace, iline)
```

Where you are looping through line by line.

Look at the [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) and [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) modules for how to wrap this up into an application if that is what you want.